# How To Pass Values in VB.net HTTP Function?

Tags: .net, vb.net, function

I want to Creating a small utility where user can send SMS through txtlocal API. The txtlocal offer code snippet for VB.net. I just create a simple form and copy-paste the code, the Credit Balance check function works fine but sending SMS through Win Form not working. Here is The Code Snippet -

Code snippet from txtlocal -

```
Private Function SendSMS_txtLocal(ByVal Test As Boolean, _
ByVal From As String, _
ByVal Message As String, _
ByVal SendTo As String, _
ByVal URL As String) As String
    ' Send a message using the txtLocal transport
    Const TransportURL As String ="http://www.txtlocal.com/sendsmspost.php"
    Const TransportUserNameAs String ="me@myemail.com"
    Const TransportPasswordAs String ="mypassword"
    Const TransportVerboseAs Boolean =True
    Dim strPost As String
    ' Build POST String
    strPost = "uname=" + TransportUserName _
    + "&pword=" + TransportPassword _
    + "&message=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Message) _
    + "&from=" + From _
    + "&selectednums=" + SendTo
    If URL  "" Then
        strPost += "&url=" + URL
    End If
    If Test = True Then
        strPost += "&test=1"
    End If
    If TransportVerbose =True Then
        strPost += "&info=1"
    End If
    ' Create POST
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(TransportURL)
    request.Method = "POST"
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strPost)
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()
    ' Get the response.
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseFromServerAs String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    ' Clean upthe streams.
    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()
    ' Return result to calling function
    If responseFromServer.Length > 0 Then
        Return responseFromServer
    Else
        Return CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription
    End If
End Function
```

And I Call the function Like This -

```
SendSMS_txtLocal(0, TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, "http://www.txtlocal.com/sendsmspost.php")
```

And Here is my Form Design -

[image]

Please Suggest - What's wrong with the code..

Thanks & Best Regards

Comment: "not working" You have to give us more info than that.

Comment: Can I post my Entire Project Code ? Please suggest Magnus..

Comment: No, only post relevant code. But tell us more about the problem you are having.

Comment: Ok..here is the scenario - txtlocal offer only a function in their website, i just copy the code and paste into my form. Public class form3 in this case. and i call the function SendSMS_txtLocal() from button1, i.e. the send sms button. But the sms can't send. :( even i can't track the error :(

Comment: I assume you have replaced `TransportUserNameAs` and `TransportPasswordAs` with your account values?

Comment: That already done..and i also change the value of test=1 to test=0. but no luck. :(

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, so I post this as a comment. If you look at their example in C# you will notice that when they write the SMS, they use a StreamWriter and not a generic Stream. You could try and check if this is of any importance.

Comment: Steve..I don't know C#. :( I am completely new in .net platform. :(

Comment: Dear Developers - Any code help with txtlocal will greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it your calling the function wrong. Try:

```
SendSMS_txtLocal(0, TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, "??")
```

The URL that you're adding isn't being used as a URL, it's being sent off to `txtlocal` in the string of info you are sending them, no idea what its for or about, have a read on their web site?